# passing arraylist of bitmap from activity to another

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an android where i want to pass a arraylist of bitmap from one activity to andother .how can i do that.

```
ArrayList<String> questionArray;

 ArrayList<Bitmap>questionBitmap=new ArrayList<Bitmap>(); questionBitmap=loadBitmapFromAllArray(questionArray);public ArrayList<Bitmap> loadBitmapFromAllArray(ArrayList<String> questionArray) 
    {
        URL questionUrl = null;
        ArrayList<Bitmap>questionBitmap=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
         for(int b =0; b <questionArray.size(); b+=1)
            {
                String questionSource=questionArray.get(b);
                try 
                {
                     questionUrl=new URL(questionSource);
                } 
                catch (MalformedURLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                questionBitmap.add(getRemoteImage(questionUrl));
            }
        return questionBitmap;  
    }
     public Bitmap getRemoteImage(final URL aURL) { 
         try {
                 final URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
                 conn.connect();
                 final BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                 final Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                 bis.close();
                 return bm;
         }
         catch (IOException e) 
         {
         }
         return null;
 }
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Can you specify what's your use case?

Answer (score 1):

```
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(arg1.getContext(), picViewer.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArray("images", your_array);
        myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
```

**EDIT**

> this could be done because Bitmap implements Parcelable!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your arraylist of bitmaps is an array of strings with the filenames of bitmaps...

Example of sending from activity A to activity B :

```
Intent i = new Intent (YourContext, ReceiverClass.class);
i.putExtra("bmpArray", yourBitmapArray);
context.startActivity(i);
```

And in the receiving activity:

```
receivingBitmapArray = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("bmpArray");
```

Comment: ArrayList<Bitmap>questionBitmap=new ArrayList<Bitmap>(); questionBitmap=loadBitmapFromAllArray(questionArray);